# Displaying single bxslider within Bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bxslider

I have several tabs within my page that show / hide content when pressed

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs propertyTabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="property-details" class="active">
      <a href="#video" aria-controls="video" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        Video
      </a>
    </li>
    <li role="property-details">
      <a href="#photos" aria-controls="photos" role="tab" id="reload-slider" data-toggle="tab">
        Photos
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I click the photos tab the bxslider should load, currently when I click photos the images don't load, all that is shown is the pagination. When I resize the browser or click the tab for a second time, the slider loads.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.property-gallery').bxSlider({
    pager: true,
    autoHover: true,
    maxSlides: 1,
    minSlides: 1,
    controls: true,
    hideControlOnEnd: false,
    moveSlides:1
  });
});
```

I've tried loads of different solutions posted but nothing has worked for me yet! I just want to reload the slider every time you click the photos tab!

My slider within the tab

```
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="photos">
      {% if property.photos.size > 0 %}
        <div class="property-gallery-container">
          <ul class="bxslider property-gallery">
            {% for photo in property.photos %}
              <li>
                <img
                  src="{{ photo | url_for_property_photo: "x500" }}"
                  data-index="{{ forloop.index0 }}"
                  alt=""
                >
              </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you are clicking before the site has loaded completly? Try to load the page, wait a minute, and click then. Does it now open immediately?

Comment: The page has definitely loaded when I click. Still having to either click the tab twice or resize browser before the slider shows

Comment: Where is this particular element `.property-gallery`? I don't see that!

Comment: The console is not showing any errors I guess?

Comment: I have added the slider code above

Answer (score 1):

Boostrap tab handles `display:none;` to hide container tabs. When BxSlider is initialized it ain't got a width/height reference to be displayed with the 100% container wide.

Adding this to your css file could fix it:

```
    .tab-content > .tab-pane,
    .pill-content > .pill-pane {
        display: block;     
        height: 0;         
        overflow-y: hidden; 
    }

  .tab-content > .active,
    .pill-content > .active {
        height: auto;      
    }
```

Here I  change display:none with display:block and I start to play with the height to hide/show container